# 500 Can't connect to example.com:443 (LWP::Protocol::https::Socket: SSL connect attempt failed with unknown error SSL wants a read first)

Tags: perl, ssl

I want to export issue from the GitLab CE using this [script.](https://gitlab.com/emobix/get-all-gitlab-issues-as-csv/blob/master/get-all-project-issues.pl)

I ran the following commands on macOS 10.10.5:

```
sudo /usr/bin/perl -MCPAN -e'install Text::CSV_XS'
sudo cpan Mozilla::CA
sudo cpan install LWP
sudo cpan LWP::Protocol::https
```

However, I still get this error:

> 500 Can't connect to gitlab.lrz.de:443 (LWP::Protocol::https::Socket: SSL connect attempt failed with unknown error SSL wants a read first) /Users/kiaora/Downloads/get-all-project-issues.pl line 41.`

This is literally my first experience with perl. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I only changed these lines:

```
my $PROJECT_ID="myProjectID"; # numeric project id, can be found in project -> general settings
my $GITLAB_API_PRIVATE_TOKEN='myToken(scope read_repository)'; # obtained from https://gitlab.lrz.de/profile/personal_access_tokens
my $baseurl = "https://gitlab.lrz.de/"; # change if using a private install
```

**EDIT:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use Text::CSV_XS qw( csv );
use JSON::PP qw(decode_json);
# Uncomment these for debugging
# use LWP::ConsoleLogger::Easy qw( debug_ua );
# use Data::Dumper;

my $PROJECT_ID="--my-project-id--"; # numeric project id, can be found in project -> general settings
my $GITLAB_API_PRIVATE_TOKEN='--my-api-private-token--'; # obtained from https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens
my $baseurl = "https://gitlab.lrz.de/"; # change if using a private install

$baseurl .= "api/v4/";
my $issuesurl = $baseurl."projects/".$PROJECT_ID."/issues";

my @issues = ();
my $page = 1;
my $totalpages;

do
{

    my %query_hash = (
        'per_page' => 100,
        'page' => $page
    );

    print "Fetching page $page".(defined($totalpages)?" (of $totalpages)":"")."\n";

    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
    # debug_ua($ua);
    $ua->default_header('PRIVATE-TOKEN' => $GITLAB_API_PRIVATE_TOKEN);

    my $uri = URI->new($issuesurl);
    $uri->query_form(%query_hash);
    my $resp = $ua->get($uri);
    if (!$resp->is_success) {
        die $resp->status_line;
    }
    $totalpages = int($resp->header("X-Total-Pages"));

    my $resptext;
    $resptext = $resp->decoded_content;

    my $issuedata = decode_json($resptext);

    push(@issues, @{$issuedata});
}
while ($page++ < $totalpages);

my $outputfname = "issues.csv";
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, eol => $/ });
open my $fh, ">", $outputfname or die "$outputfname: $!";

my @headings = [
    "URL",
    "Milestone",
    "Author",
    "Title",
    "Description",
    "State",
    "Assignees",
    "Labels",
    "Created At",
    "Updated At",
    "Closed At",
    "Due date",
    "Confidental",
    "Weight",
    "Locked",
    "Time estimate",
    "Time spent",
    "Human Time estimate",
    "Human Time spent",
];
$csv->print ($fh, @headings) or $csv->error_diag;

foreach my $i (@issues)
{
#    print Dumper([$i])."\n";
    my @values = [
        $i->{'web_url'},
        $i->{'milestone'}->{'title'},
        $i->{'author'}->{'username'},
        $i->{'title'},
        $i->{'description'},
        $i->{'state'},
        join(',', map {$_->{'username'}} @{$i->{'assignees'}}),
        join(',', @{$i->{'labels'}}),
        $i->{'created_at'},
        $i->{'updated_at'},
        $i->{'closed_at'},
        $i->{'due_date'},
        $i->{'confidential'},
        $i->{'weight'},
        $i->{'discussion_locked'},
        $i->{'time_stats'}->{'time_estimate'},
        $i->{'time_stats'}->{'total_time_spent'},
        $i->{'time_stats'}->{'human_time_estimate'},
        $i->{'time_stats'}->{'human_total_time_spent'},
        $i->{'closed_by'}->{'username'},

    ];
    $csv->print ($fh, @values) or $csv->error_diag;    
}

close $fh or die "$outputfname: $!";

print "Issues saved to $outputfname\n";
```

Comment: You could've shortened those installation commands to `sudo cpan Text::CSV_XS Mozilla::CA LWP LWP::Protocol::https`. And `cpan install` is unnecessary because that installs `install.pm`, which is a dummy module and never used. Also, `sudo cpan` is a generally a bad idea.

Comment: If you need help with debugging Perl code, you should post that code. On the other hand, if you're merely trying to use a tool that happens to be written in Perl, you're on the wrong site: StackOverflow is for questions about programming. Try https://superuser.com/ maybe? Or does this tool have an official support forum?

Comment: @melpomene thanks for the advice. I'll keep it in mind. Any idea how to deal with the error? As I mentioned in the question I have no idea how perl works, at all. Did my fair share of googling, this is how I figured out the commands listed in the question. I'll add the code of the script, though.

Comment: You are running an older version of macOS which suggests that you also use the long outdated version 0.9.8 of OpenSSL which got shipped with old macOS versions. This version does not have any support for TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 but the server needs at least support for TLS 1.1. Please check your version of OpenSSL with `perl -MNet::SSLeay -E 'say Net::SSLeay::SSLeay_version'`.

Comment: Thanks Steffen! I was indeed running `OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015` I promptly installed openssl via homebrew and then updated `sudo cpan  Net::SSLeay`

Comment: I still get one minor error `Wide character in print at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/IO/Handle.pm line 420.`But a csv file is created nevertheless!